# c# regex - groups and nested groups

Tags: c#, regex

The structure is a list of playlists. A playlist consists of:
- A static text and the date;
- 1-n tracks consisting of an index, an author, a title

```
STATICTEXT 2011-06-18      
---------------------
01. author - title
02. author - title

STATICTEXT 2011-06-19
---------------------
01. author - title
02. author - title
03. author - title
04. author - title
```

I'd like to capture a list of playlist. Inside a playlist block, I'd like to captue other information, such as author and title.
To me this is an example of nested groups: each playlist is a group containing 2 nested groups (author, title).

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

R.

Comment: Is there any special reason why you insist on doing this with regular expressions?

Comment: This is an off site project. I know regex provides enough flexibility to do it. But I don't know how :)

Comment: Depending on the size of the input a solution with capturing the entire input with one regex could end up being rather slow. Can you give a more real world example of the data? Things that matter: Is STATICTEXT a simple alphanumeric string or may it contain whitespace or special characters? Can you be sure that author and title do not contain hyphens (-) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions are great at certain things, but not for all things. Writing a parser for this file is simple and straight forward.

```
playlists = new List()
for line in file
  if line is blank
    continue
  if line starts with "STATICTEXT"
    playslists.add(playlist)
    playlist = new Playlist()
  song = parse song //this is something that regex does good
  playlist.add(song)
```

Comment: +1 for "use the right tool for the job". Regexes have their uses, but can be complicated, slow/inefficient, and difficult to debug/maintain in some cases. (Unless the OP is more interested in learning about regexes than solving the specific example, in which case this answer isn't vey helpful ;-)

Comment: @Jason, thanks for the empathy ;) The stuff I want to achieve is for my own learning of the tool :)